# Unity visual scripting bolt Graph Inspector not showing Blackboard layout

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Bolt visual scripting is showing blackboard in full screen as below :

[image]

But not in windowed screen
[image]

How can I enable this on windowed screen ?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually variables to be toggled

[image]